# Add 'Enlarge' option to code blocks

Tags: feature-request, code-block

I would like an 'enlarge' option for text blocks that are wider than the window, such as an enlarge link below wider blocks, or something similar.
[image: enlarge]

I did find [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92179/resizable-text-blocks) about resizable text blocks, which would be fine, too, but the answers don't seem to fit how I see SE working in my browsers. The answer from Cody Gray I can't repeat on any of my browsers (I can't resize any of the blocks, can you?). Reformatting an entire log snippet to fit the window is tedious and I find harder to read than having everything on one line.

I did observe that the site is slightly wider on my 2560 wide monitor than on my 800 wide tablet, but only by about 6 characters.

In the Android app, I can click on a text block and have it move to the foreground and be as wide as the screen. I would like to have this functionality in the desktop version of the site, as well.

Comment: Which answer are you referring to? I am on my phone right now, but my understanding is that the greasemonkey solution is no longer an option.

Comment: Answers are not really relevant, the question itself is a dupe, i.e. this feature was already requested.

Comment: So, when the flag states, "this question has been asked before and already has an answer," that last part isn't relevant?

Comment: True, in feature requests on meta sites it's not relevant in case the answers are just user suggestions and not official response. Meta is different in many things, e.g. voting work in a different way as well. (downvote usually doesn't mean bad quality or lack of research, just the downvoter disagrees with the suggested feature)

Comment: @Paul The greasemonkey script is working for me ...